# Mongodb query params ( combine $gt with $in )

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using api query params library
`rooms=2,4,5&rooms>=6`
this gives
`rooms: { '$gte': 6, '$in': [ 2, 4, 5 ] }`
This won't work but if i search with only `rooms>=6` it works or with `rooms=2,4,5`.
How i can combine $gte with $in ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to OR if the same key has multiple conditions. (I want all rooms, 2, 4, 5 OR greater than 6.)

To do that in mongo:

```
$or: [
   {rooms: { $gte: 6}},
   {rooms: { $in: [2, 4, 5]}}
]
```

Comment: Thank you that's right, do you have some library that can make this easy ?

Comment: @TodorPavlovic unfortunately I don't know of one.

Answer (score 1):

You can  also use not in for your query like
db.inventory.find( { rooms: { $nin: [ 1, 6] } } )

Answer (score 0):

So guys i did this with $nin operator.

First i'm using api-query-params library.

```
let { filter, skip, limit, sort } = aqp(req.query)
```

It can parse query param --- `rooms=1,2,3,4,5`
into  `'rooms': { '$in': [ 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 5 ] }`

But if we want when user adds 5 to be $gte  5

```
function addOrOperator(filter, field) {
  //if selected value is undefined return
  if(!filter[field]) return;

  //values to match 
  let array = [0,1,2,3,4,5];
  
  //if 5 is only selected returned value is 'rooms': 5
  if(filter[field] === 5) {
    filter[field] = {
      $gte: 5
    }
  }

  if(filter[field].$in) {
    if(filter[field].$in.includes(5)) {
      let difference = array.filter(x => !filter[field].$in.includes(x));
      filter[field] = {
        $nin: [...difference, null, ""]
      }
    }
  }

  return filter;
}
```

Then we are calling this function inside controller

```
addOrOperator(filter, 'rooms'); // all filters and key that we want to select
```